# Application.Exit() not working

Tags: c#, .net

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Exit();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
```

Why after calling Application.Exit(), application doesn't exit immediately? After this line, Form1 still shows. How to exit application immediately. Thanks.

**Notes:**this is only an example. I handle some functions before showing form. And in functions, I have a command code to call Application.Exit() but I wonder why application doesn't exit immediately.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: You're showing Form1 on last line, isn't it the reason?

Comment: Why would you want to start an application without even run it really?

Comment: Hi all, this is only an example. I handle some functions before showing form. And in function, I call Application.Exit() but I wonder why application doesn't exit immediately.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx) says:

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

The problem is the message pump for your application wont start until after you call Run and the Form is created.

> The Exit method is typically called from within a message loop, and forces Run to return.

Comment: @SwDevMan81: After the call? When Run returns the message pump is already gone ;p

Comment: You don't have to put Application.Exit(); in this main function. The application exits automatically when Form1 is closed.

Comment: My code is an example. I will handle some function before calling to show form. Example: I check to update for my program. I need a good solution to exit application immediately and avoid calling to next line. Thanks.

Comment: After calling Application.Exit(), I have any methods (or properties) to check Application.Exit() was called. EX: BackgroundWorker object have a method CancelAsync and I can check it's state using property CancellationPending = true.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314072/how-to-immediately-exit-a-windows-form-net-application

Comment: Genius!! My problem was that I have a while loop that never ends, so the program never ends!! Put a flag with a break and worked!

Answer (score 52):

Well logically it cannot work. The `Application` cannot exit if it is not running.

It would be better to use `Environment.Exit` here.

Comment: Precisely, Environment.Exit(int returnCode), where returnCode = 0 if all is good.

Answer (score 17):

[Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the "nice way" of shutting down a program. Outstanding windows messages are processed and only then are all windows closed. This also means, that `Application.Exit` only has meaning when the Windows message loop is running, that is, when the program is inside `Application.Run`. You call `Application.Exit` before `Application.Run`, so there is no message loop to exit.

From the documentation:

> Informs all message pumps that they
>   must terminate, and then closes all
>   application windows after the messages
>   have been processed.

What you are looking for is probably [System.Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx), which more or less kills the process. `Environment.Exit` still does some clean-up. If you need to terminate the process immediately, you can use [System.Environment.FailFast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.failfast.aspx).

Comment: This also works if your application **has no windows**.

Answer (score 8):

The code below should help you.

```
        if (Application.MessageLoop)
            Application.Exit();
        else
            Environment.Exit(1);
```

Answer (score 6):

Add a `return;` statement instead of `Application.Exit();`

Comment: By far the simplest solution, and it uses native c++ logic. Worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The application is not even running at that point.  Calling exit has no effect.  In the main function you want to return.  Like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        return;
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN, `Application.Exit()`

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

Since there are no application windows yet, nothing happens (as I understand it). Then you start the application afterwards, because `Application.Exit()` does not as you think stop program execution.

I assume your problem is not actually as trivially simple as you described in the question - in any case simply `return;`ing without ever calling `Application.Run()` is probably the solution.