# Application not close

Tags: c#

When I enter an incorrect database in the above code, the catch part catches the error but does not close the application. a simple error, but could not solve.

```
OleDbConnection conn;
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=xx.accdb";
public void connect()
{
    conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        this.conn.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error.");
        Aplication.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend against writing your code all in one line. It makes it very hard to read.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978034/9801177

Comment: Also if that is your code Application is written with double p

Comment: Is this code in a modal dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Environment.Exit()`.
check this related question for more info :

[Application.Exit() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991249/application-exit-not-working)

Also note that `MessageBox.Show("Error.")` will block the execution flow until you click OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
 conn.Close(); //dont forget

Environment.Exit(0) //or use -> System.Environment.Exit(0);
```